# tail command not working with nodejs exec command

Tags: node.js, shell, tail, openwrt

I'm writing a quick test script that uses the tail command to monitor output that is added to a log file. When I execute the tail command directly in the console (I'm using OpenWRT), it works fine as expected:

```
tail -F /var/log/2022-04-26-system_server.log
```

Here's the program I made to test this out:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("tail -F /var/log/2022-04-26-system_server.log", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

But when I run the script, it just sits there and nothing happens when new text is appended to the file. What am I missing??

Comment: It might be buffering the output

Comment: Hmm..... maybe that is why the event works but the inline function doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I needed to add an event to listen for incoming data on stdout (not sure why). Here's the code I added that fixed the problem:

```
var logOutput = ""
theProcess.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
    logOutput += chunk.toString();
});
```

The output then goes into the string.

Comment: It's likely that the callback version isn't called until the stream is closed, which never happens with `-f`. This version is called whenever there is new data, even before the stream is closed.